# Calling the same PHP script containing a sleep function via AJAX or CRON JOB

Tags: php, ajax, cron, sleep

I have a PHP script which retrieves X records from a database, and loops through them at a rate of 1 every 10 seconds.

The same script must work with both a Cron Job, and an AJAX call via browser.

The cron part seems to work fine, I have a "master" cron job running every minute on my server, which then retrieves jobs defined in a database (with their own timing and configuration) and handles them with a curl_multi_init() logic.

The faulty part is that calling the script via AJAX freezes my entire web application until the script finishes its execution.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public function getAndHandleData() : array {

  //instantiate db class and variables

  $data = $database->getData();
  $sleepTime = 60/$requestsPerMinute;

  foreach ($data as $k => $v) {

            // call function which does a curl request to a web service
            // handle response

            if ($k !== array_key_last($data)) {
                // wait $sleepTime seconds before doing the next iteration, unless it's the last
                sleep(ceil($sleepTime));  
            }
        }
}
```

The JQuery AJAX call which freezes my app until it completes:

```
function apiRequestHandler(type, params) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/route_calling_the_same_php_function',
        data: {
            'type' : type,
            'params' : params,
        },
        cache: false,
        timeout: 800000,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            const success = data['success'] ?? null

            if (success) {...}
         },
         error: {...}
    });
}
```

Comment: PHP is not inherently multithreaded so this is always a danger when having a long-running process triggered through the webserver. Why does the job need to sleep in between rows, instead of processing them all immediately? Also, why do you even need to be able to call this through the webserver, if the cron job is already running every minute? Surely that's frequent enough?

Comment: Basically the API i'm calling has a 10 requests per minute limit, and it returns an error if i make the 10 requests all in a short span of time.
Also the cron in production will likely run every 15-30 minutes, but the user must be able to call it on-demand. Data is processed in the span of a minute and results will be available on another page.
Ideally the on-demand call is a bit overkill, but it's a feature i'd like to have nonetheless

Comment: Realistically then you need to find a way of triggering it as a background process, and then notifying the user when it's done. Maybe you _do_ have the cron set to run every minute in production, but have some extra data which tells it when it should actually next process the data. By default that would be saved so it is every 30 mins or whatever, but your AJAX route could set some data to overwrite that with a timestamp in the immediate future, so next time cron triggers it reads that and knows it's time to run the job fully. And maybe also a flag to say "send an email to X when it's done"

Comment: I already have a system that has task timings declared in a database table, my cron job is actually just one and _does_ run every minute, then checks said table and calls the scripts/services with curl_multi_exec().
So yea it's more of an "admin" function after all.
I'm reading about Enqueue libraries, could that be the case?

Comment: Session locking could be one of the possible culprits if `session_start()` is involved somehow.

Comment: @nice_dev I've literally just now explored that solution and it works for my use case. I'll update the post with an own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved:**

The problem is caused by PHP session management, which locks the session file when a script is being executed, even if sleeping.

Using `session_write_close()` before the loop+sleep solves the app freezing, while the task runs in the background, even if switching to another page.

Final working pseudo-code:

```
public function getAndHandleData() : array {

  //instantiate db class and variables

  $data = $database->getData();
  $sleepTime = 60/$requestsPerMinute;

  // locks session to prevent system freeze
  session_write_close();

  foreach ($data as $k => $v) {

            // call function which does a curl request to a web service
            // handle response

            if ($k !== array_key_last($data)) {
                // wait $sleepTime seconds before doing the next iteration, unless it's the last
                sleep(ceil($sleepTime));  
            }
        }
}
```